# $\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k - \log n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I got this question : 
$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k  - \log n$$
I proved that $\lim a_n $  exist.
Now I have to prove: $$ 0<a_n-\lim a_n\le \frac 1n  $$ 
for every $n \in \mathbb N$.

I tried induction,without any luck in the induction step.
I think there is another way , maybe, with integrals.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: $an - \lim(an)$ - I do not understand. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: You probably mean $a_n$

Comment: Check $\gamma$, Euler's other constant

Comment: for proving it converges you used that $\int_1^{k+1} \frac{dt}{t} < \sum_{k = 1}^n 1/k < 1+\int_1^k \frac{dt}{t}$

Comment: yeah i used that , and the fact that the sequence is bounded.

Comment: by Lim(an) i meant lim(an) when n goes to infinity.

Comment: This question just asks for the rate of convergence of $a_n$ to its limit $\gamma$, specifically that $a_n-\gamma\le\dfrac1n$. I don't see what's unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given inequality is equivalent with 
$$1+\cdots +\frac{1}{n-1}-\ln n < \gamma$$
It now follows by remarking that 
$$b_n=1+\cdots +\frac{1}{n}-\ln (n+1)$$ (which has the same limit $\gamma$ as $a_n$) is increasing. This being easy to see from the inequality $$\ln (1+\frac{1}{n})\leq \frac{1}{n}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle (\lim a_n) -a_n = \sum_{k=n}^\infty a_{k+1}-a_k = \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k+1} - \ln\left(1-\frac{1}{k+1} \right)$

Since $\forall x> 0, x-\frac{x^2}2\leq \ln(1+x)< x$,

$$-\frac 12 \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \leq  (\lim a_n) -a_n < 0$$

A standard integral estimate yields $\displaystyle \frac 12 \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\leq \frac 12 \int_{n-1}^\infty \frac 1{(t+1)^2} dt = \frac 1{2n}$, hence the result $$0<a_n-\lim a_n\le \frac 1n$$